# How to Fix blank pages on Spotify?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, 12.10, spotify

Sometimes spotify show blanks pages and not load anything

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had this problem?

Write the following in the terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/spotify && rm -r ~/.config/spotify
```

**Note**: This will clear all local Spotify settings. Playlists, ratings, etc. should not be affected.

Then restart spotify, and it's all. :-D

[image]

Comment: This made appear "Discover can't be loaded at this moment. Please, try again in a bit" the first time I open spotify. Then, again always a blank page

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in my case that Spotify still responded to play/stop commands etc, only the UI wasn't loading. I wasn't able to control it remotely though so I figured it must be running in offline mode. I probably closed it while in offline mode. I disabled offline mode in the blank screen with shortcut `ctrl + shift + o` and restarted Spotify which fixed it.